# Unable to Upload the file using Uploadify script

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the Uploadify Plugin to Upload files. although this might be a very basic question i am unable to understand and implement to get it work to upload the files.

I want to achieve the following using uploadify

when a user select the file i want it to be directly uploaded to the target path using PHP.

now i am using the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uploadify.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someID').uploadify({ 
      'uploader': 'img/uploadify.swf',
      'script': 'uploadify.php',
      'folder': 'upload',
      'cancelImg': 'img/cancel.png',
      'auto': 'true',
      'fileDesc': 'jpg/jpeg',
      'displayData': 'percentage',
      'fileExt': "*.jpg;*.jpeg",
      'sizeLimit' : '8388608'
      }); }); 
      </script>

<body>
<form id="someID" action="uploadify.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileUpload1"/>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /></p> 
</form>
</body>
```

and this is the code for uploadify.php

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo "1";
```

I just want to upload a single file. do i need to include the check.php for that. how do i make something like when a user select the image file it directly performs the operation and move to the designated directory.

P.S: I have the very basic understanding of javascript and jquery. :)

Note : file uploading problem is solved now.

> how do i limit the user from uploading
>   just one file on one button, i want
>   something like when  a user select the
>   file and it gets uploaded that button
>   should be disabled or something

EDIT : for limiting the users from uploading multiple file in a button i added this code and it is still uploading many files as and when users select multiple times. here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someID').uploadify({ 
      'uploader': 'img/uploadify.swf',
      'script': 'uploadify.php',
      'folder': 'upload',
      'cancelImg': 'img/cancel.png',
      'auto': 'true',
      'fileDesc': 'jpg/jpeg',
      'displayData': 'percentage',
      'fileExt': "*.jpg;*.jpeg",
      'sizeLimit' : '8388608',
      'fileDataName' : 'file',
      onSelect : function(){
           $("#someID input").attr("disabled", true);
      }
      }); }); 
      </script>
```

what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wrangling with this a few weeks ago. You need to change your `fileDataName` attribute. By default, it is `Filedata`. You are trying to access it as `file` in this part: `$_FILES['file']`.

Either change all instances of `$_FILES['file']` to `$_FILES['Filedata']` or add this attribute to your `$('#someID').uploadify({});` attribute collection: `fileDataName:'file'`.

If you are looking for a drop-in fix, just make this change in your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someID').uploadify({ 
      'uploader': 'img/uploadify.swf',
      'script': 'uploadify.php',
      'folder': 'upload',
      'cancelImg': 'img/cancel.png',
      'auto': 'true',
      'fileDesc': 'jpg/jpeg',
      'displayData': 'percentage',
      'fileExt': "*.jpg;*.jpeg",
      'sizeLimit' : '8388608',
      'fileDataName' : 'file'
      }); 
});
```

Note the `'fileDataName' : 'file'`

**To limit a single upload (as long as the page isn't refreshed, of course):**

Change your JavaScript to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someID').uploadify({ 
      'uploader': 'img/uploadify.swf',
      'script': 'uploadify.php',
      'folder': 'upload',
      'cancelImg': 'img/cancel.png',
      'auto': 'true',
      'fileDesc': 'jpg/jpeg',
      'displayData': 'percentage',
      'fileExt': "*.jpg;*.jpeg",
      'sizeLimit' : '8388608',
      onSelect : function(){
           $("#someID input").attr("disabled", true);
      }}); 
});
```

Just know that if the user refreshes the page, the button will be enabled again allowing them to upload another file. They can also re-enable it manually. So, add a server-side check to make sure that they don't upload another file if you don't want them to.

Comment: wow, working perfectly, it is moving the file. now how do i limit the user from uploading just one file on one button, i want something like when  a user select the file and it gets uploaded that button should be disabled or something

Comment: I added an example in the answer

Comment: i tried using the code and it is still able to upload many file. i am updating the code above please take a look. where i am going wrong.

Comment: Try changing the line `$("#someID input").attr("disabled", true);` to `$("#someID input").remove();`. Now when you upload a file, are the inputs removed? (I'm testing to see if the event fires successfully and if the right things are selected.)

Comment: nope not working? it is not running that function i guess. :( , i tried changing the form to match the above also wrapped the form around with div id matching above. it is not working at all.

Comment: Hmmm... try changing `onSelect` to `onProgress`.

Comment: You might have noticed that the original file input tag with #someID gets hidden and is replaced by an object when the page is ready. So, I think, when you again try to disable the file #someID it does not work. You have to disable the object instead.

Comment: Sorry, I can't spot the problem. Try posting a new question asking about this problem to attract more people.

Comment: correction in my last comment... "the original file input tag with `#someID` gets hidden and an object with `#fileUploader` is added next to it when the page is ready."
check if `$("object#fileUploader").attr("display","none");` works? Then you can insert a faded file upload button there to mimic the file input disabling action. I think that did not work for me. So, I edited the jquery library's code where it inserts the `object#fileUploader`. Instead of adding next to the file input tag, I mafe it to appear inside a `div#holder`. Then I did `$(div#holder").attr(innerHTML,"")`.

Comment: Hi guys thanks you for tips and tricks, i did it finally, did something like. onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, reposnse, data) 
      {
     $('#filesUploaded').append('<a href='+fileObj.filePath+'>'+fileObj.name+'</a><br>');
     $("#firstUpload").remove();
     }

and wrapped the input with that div, now i have the file name printed on screen as well as the button is hidden on completion of the file upload.

Comment: @Sandeepan Thank you! I knew I was missing something. The object that replaces the button is the Flash uploader

Answer (score 1):

Some points to consider:

1. Checking for the existence of `$_FILES` is not the proper way to confirm an upload. If an upload fails for any reason (file too large, connection died, out of disk space, etc..), there will STILL be a `$_FILES` array. You need to do something like  \

   `if ($_FILES['nameoffield']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)` instead.

   Error constants are defined here: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
2. Your path building code as is opens your server completely to a remote file-based takeover: you're blindly using `$_REQUEST['folder']` in your path. What if someone subverts the form and sets folder to `../../../../../../../../some/nasty/place/on/your/system`?
3. There's no collision detection, so your script will happily overwrite an existing file with the uploaded one
4. You don't check if the `move_uploaded_file()` actually succeeded. It returns boolean `FALSE` if it couldn't move the file for whatever reason. You just blindly echo out a '1' to inform the client-side javascript that something happened.

Comment: How would you prevent someone from abusing security hole #2? (No sarcasm intended, I'm just curious). Would you check the path's parent?

Comment: FYI this is my first jquery script and it is purely meant for testing, i do have a code which checks on all sorts of error like (file_exists) just in case, it renames the file before moving, it checks the file dimensions etc etc. am looking for the solution because i want to implement Uploadify in my Custom CMS. BTW thank you for that tip, i learned something out of it.. :)

Comment: I guess you could just filter `../` from the path?

Comment: Best is to not let the user specify a path at all. Treat anything the user supplies, including the uploaded file itself, as toxic waste and make sure you're wearing full hazmat gear while working on it.